In which file is stored the screen backlight brightness settings?
I would like to make a Debian 12 Live system for a laptop, from another computer that has an external display without backlight settings in the operating system.
I need to know the file where is stored the backlight brightness settings, to copy it in the Live system, so that the backlight will be already adjusted when I will boot the live system.
The live system will use MATE desktop environment, a fork of GNOME. I wonder if the backlight configuration is part of gsettings ?
And so, which file I will have to copy, once the backlight brightness adjusted ?

In MATE desktop environment, backlight brightness settings are parts of gsettings.
They are stored in the schema: org.mate.power-manager
It is possible to list the keys of this schema:
gsettings list-keys org.mate.power-manager

There are some brightness keys like brightness-ac
All modifications done to default gsettings seems to be stored in the file $HOME/.config/dconf/user
So, after having adjusted the brightness on the laptop, it is this file I have to copy to the user directory $HOME/.config/dconf/ of the Live system I want to make.
It is also possible to get the value of a gsetting:
gsettings get org.mate.power-manager brightness-ac

And to set it to another value:
gsettings set org.mate.power-manager brightness-ac 30.0

By this way, it is possible to set a gsetting even if it is not displayed in the mate power-manager applet.

You can assign such as :
echo 200 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

